# Cannot change or get Session from Controller

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, session

i am working on a project on ASP.NET MVC, and i need to use Session to store some data.

This is the code:

HomeController.cs

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public HomeController()
    {
    }

    public void ChangeValue(){
        //I get userId with some other data from db and set to session
        //but for the sake of simplicity i set here to 10.
        Session["getSession"] = "10";
    }

    //I use this method only for getting the changed session value
    public ActionResult GetWaiting()
        {
            //now i just need to return the changed value
            return Json(Session["getSession"], JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
}
```

Web.config

```
<system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.6.1" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.6.1" />
    <httpModules>
          <add name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ApplicationInsightsHttpModule, Microsoft.AI.Web" />
    </httpModules>
    <sessionState mode="InProc" timeout="1" cookieless="true" />
</system.web>
```

Index.cshtml

```
<h1 id="session"></h1>
@section scripts{

<script>
    $(function () {
        function getWait() {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'http://localhost:50325/Home/GetWaiting',
                success: function (data) {
                    $('#session').text('@Session["getSession"]');
                }
            });
        }

        setInterval(function () {
            getWait();
        }, 1000);
})
</script>

}
```

But the problem is that everytime i try to get data from that Session, it returns null (just like i never used it).
I also tried setting Session with System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["getSession"] but still the same, it does not make any changes.
I also tried changing timeout and removing cookieless from  in Web.config but still the same.

p.s. I need to store that value to Session, beucase the value is being changed by another method, and i just need to retrieve the new value that has been set by another method.

Comment: `@Session["getSession"]` in your script is razor code - its evaluated on the server before you view is sent to the browser. It does not 'magically' update just because some server side code changed it. You need to send the updated value back to the client

Comment: `public ActionResult GetWaiting()` method should be inside `HomeController() `  class block which should inherit `Controller` class of mvc. Session should be set inside your action method. There are some typo in your code.

Comment: @StephenMuecke just updated my question take a look quickly if u can.

Comment: @stom just updated my question take a look quickly if u can.

Comment: You cannot just completely change your question and invalidate the comments and answers that have need added (I have rolled back your changes). If you want to add other code you have tried, append it to your original question

Comment: @StephenMuecke is it ok now?

Comment: That fine - you just need update the DOM in the `success` callback as per Nitesh's answer (but its completely unclear what your `ChangeValue()` methods is doing or where its being called from. And you methods are still not inside the `Controller` as noted by @stom but I assume that is just a typo)

Comment: I just added the methods inside Controller so you dont have any confusion.
Okay so that ChangeValue() in my code is a delegate that runs all the time to detect calls, and when it detects any call, it returns the number of calls. ex.10. So in order to get that value in real time i need that method to set that value to Session, and then retrieve it every 1 seconds.

Comment: Then you should be asking a new question showing where and how that method is being called (and clearly its not _detecting any call_ since you not calling it in the `GetWaiting()` method :) - you already have a correct answer to this question.

Comment: @StephenMuecke here it is the new question 
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47630869/cannot-retrieve-session-value-in-asp-net-mvc

Answer (score 1):

In GetWaiting method return the value of session as below

```
public ActionResult GetWaiting()
{
    //I get userId with some other data from db and set to session
    //but for the sake of simplicity i set here to 10.
    Session["getSession"] = "10";
    var data = Session["getSession"];
    return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

and in script assign that returned value.

```
success: function (data) {
    $('#session').text(data);
}
```

Comment: Just updated my question with my real code, take a look quickly if you can.

Comment: @ErtanHasani , this answer will work and return value 10 to the client , you can populate the value in your `html` element.

Comment: Yep but why i really need is just to get the current sessionValue that has been set by another method. So in GetWaiting should be only var data = Session["getSession"], and when i get that data it returns null.

Comment: @Ertan Hasani , in your code  `ChangeValue()` sets the `Session` but are you calling that method before calling `GetWaiting` method ? If not then you should set the session  first by doing another `GET` request from client and then call `GetWaiting` method.

Comment: @stom  ChangeValue() in my code is a delegate that runs all the time to detect calls, and when it detects any call, it returns the number of calls ex.10. So in order to get that value in real time i need that method to set that value to Session, and then retrieve it every 1 seconds by the GetWaiting method.

Comment: @ErtanHasani , okay so in your code we cant see how you call the `ChangeValue()` method ? , You should first call that method to set your session.

Comment: @stom im going to create another question for that, since i cant change this one.

Comment: @stom here it is the new question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47630869/cannot-retrieve-session-value-in-asp-net-mvc