# Cannot retrieve Session Value in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, session

i am working on a project that i need to set some value in Session and then retrieve it. But the problem is that always it returns null.

HomeController.cs

```
public class HomeController: Controller
{
    public HomeController()
    {
        Connect();
    }

    public async Task Connect()
    {
        pbx.WaitingCallsChanged += Changed;
        pbx.PhoneCallsChanged += PhoneChanged;
    }

    public void PhoneChanged(object sender, PhoneChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        //when this method is triggered set this value to session
        Session["all"] = e.Active;
    }

    private void Changed(object sender, WaitingCallsChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        //when this method is triggered set this value to session
        Session["waiting"] = e.Queue;
    }

    public ActionResult GetWaiting()
    {
        //when this method is called with ajax return only current Session values
        return Json(new { waiting = Session["waiting"], all = Session["all"] }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    } 
}
```

Web.config

```
<system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.6.1" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.6.1" />
    <httpModules>
      <add name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ApplicationInsightsHttpModule, Microsoft.AI.Web" />
    </httpModules>
    <sessionState mode="InProc" timeout="1" cookieless="true" />
</system.web>
```

Index.cshtml.cs

```
<div id='all'></div>
<div id='waiting'></div>
@section scripts{

<script>
$(function () {
    function getWait() {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://localhost:50325/Home/GetWaiting',
            success: function (data) {
                $('#all').text(data.all);
                $('#session').text(data.waiting);
            }
        });
    }

    setInterval(function () {
        getWait();
    }, 10);
})
</script>

}
```

What i have right here is that PhoneChanged and Changed are delegates methods that are being called based on those pbx.WaitingCallsChanged and pbx.PhoneCallsChaged.

So when one of these two methods is being called, i need that value to store on Session so i can get it in 'real-time' with ajax every 10 miliseconds from GetWaiting() method.

p.s. Can the problem be because every new ajax call i made, it creates a new instance of controller, and when new instance is created it sets Session to null?

Comment: Are you saying that the value of  `Session["waiting"]` and `Session["all"]` are both `null`? (and why have you set `sessionState timeout` to such a low value?)

Comment: @StephenMuecke yep thats the problem, they are both null all the time, i kept changing that from 1 to 100 while testing but still the same.

Comment: Also Can you `Debug` and check by keeping Breakpoint on methods `PhoneChanged` and `Changed` whether they are called on change ?

Comment: @stom yes they do. I also tried adding in Controller constructor a default value Session["all"] = 1; and it does save as 1, but id does not change it later.

Comment: @stom take a look at that p.s. that i added in the end of the question.

Comment: @StephenMuecke take a look at that p.s. that i added in the end of the question.

Comment: No - a new instance of your controller is created, but `Session` remains the same (until it expires or is recycled)

Comment: What is `pbx` where you attached the eventhandler to? It looks like the Connect-methot may come on a different session so your variables will never fit together. Maybe you could use `Application[""]` as the numbers are from a global context?

Comment: You're using cookieless session state - are you sending the session ID in the request URL?

Comment: Yo guys i guess the problem is that the methods that used to change the value are delegates that work with threads, so HttpContext does not work with threads i guess.

Comment: Not sure whether you got the solution , to check try to Set and Get `Session` in `PhoneChanged` method check [this](https://pastebin.com/Jqy4dJyv) code in paste bin.

Comment: It throws System.NullReferenceException. p.s. i guess i'm gonna need to use SignalR to get in real-time